# Terminal Block Connector SMT/SMD Version

Tags: connector, surface-mount

I am working with a motherboard PCB that has [these](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/tbp03r2-350.pdf) 3.5mm pitch 10pos terminal block on it for wiring harnesses. I want to replace these wiring harnesses with another accessory PCB now but I am running into the issue of there being no SMT plug in versions for the terminal block. Mate series options are [here](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/connector-mating-guide/tbp03r2-350-series). Does anyone know of either;

a) An SMT/SMD version of a terminal block?

b) Some mate pair that are 1 row, 10pos, 3.5mm pitch that I could rework to work with both boards? (an example would be something like this [male](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/weidm%C3%BCller/1838060000/4019310) block and this [female](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/weidm%C3%BCller/1630790000/4011280) but at the 3.5mm pitch, the example is at 5.08mm unfortunately)

Picture of the existing connector style I am trying to plug into with PCB instead of wiring harness:

[image]

Comment: These look similar to the Phoenix Contact MC series. There’s also a zillion other clone manufacturers.

Comment: Supposedly, Amphenol Anytek makes them: https://www.digikey.com/short/5cz5qwfn . But there's no stock.